# Nested cut function for create a frequency table

Tags: r, dataframe, cut, frequency-analysis

I am carrying out a frequency table, just for example from the airquality dataset. Below the code:

```
attach(airquality)
airquality <- airquality
breaks = seq(1.7, 20.7, by=3.8)
airquality.split = cut(airquality$Wind, breaks, right=FALSE)
airquality.freq = table(airquality.split)
airquality.dist = cbind(airquality.freq,100*airquality.freq/sum(airquality.freq),
       cumsum(airquality.freq), 100*cumsum(airquality.freq)/sum(airquality.freq))
colnames(airquality.dist) = c('Frequency','Percentage', 'Cum.Frequency','Cum.Percentage')
```

I would like to make the same operation but considering the factor `Month`. I mean to obtain a whole dataframe with the frequency of the Wind variable nested in every month, so as to create an Histogram.

```
Month                           Frequency Percentage Cum.Frequency Cum.Percentage
Month 1          [1.7,5.5)          [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 1          [5.5,9.3)          [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 1          [9.3,13.1)         [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 1          [13.1,16.9)        [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 1          [16.9,20.7)        [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 2          [1.7,5.5)          [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 2          [5.5,9.3)          [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 2          [9.3,13.1)         [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 2          [13.1,16.9)        [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]
Month 2          [16.9,20.7)        [...]  [...]           [...]       [...]

[...]
```

With these data I would like to make a histogram with different series `month` having the same color, and within the month the five columns of the percentages (or Frequency).  Is it possible to make this directly with `cut` function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is recommended to ask only one question per post. Plotting histogram can be asked as a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut` you can break `Wind` into different groups and for each `Month` calculate ratio using `prop.table`.

```
library(dplyr)

airquality %>%
  count(Month, group = cut(Wind, breaks, right=FALSE), name = 'Frequency') %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = prop.table(Frequency) * 100, 
         Cum.Frequency = cumsum(Frequency), 
         Cum.Percentage = Cum.Frequency/max(Cum.Frequency) * 100) %>%
  ungroup
```